# Configurable product dropdown is not working in quick view

Tags: configurable-product, ajax, prototype-js

I am trying to get drop down   of a configurable  in quick view of a configurable product thus i will cart the product.all content is coming  from ajax.

```
     <dl>
                <dt><label class="required"><em>*</em>Pack Size</label></dt>
            <dd class="last">
                <div class="input-box">
                    <select name="super_attribute[136]" id="attribute136" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
                        <option>Size</option>
                      </select>
                  </div>
            </dd>
            </dl>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var spConfig = new Product.Config({"attributes":{"136":{"id":"136","code":"pack_size","label":"Pack Size","options":[{"id":"26","label":"350 gm","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["101"]},{"id":"36","label":"100 gm","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["91"]},{"id":"77","label":"59 gm","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["87"]}]}},"template":"Rs. #{price}","basePrice":"50","oldPrice":"50","productId":"1387","chooseText":"Choose an Option...","taxConfig":{"includeTax":false,"showIncludeTax":false,"showBothPrices":false,"defaultTax":0,"currentTax":0,"inclTaxTitl

e":"Incl. Tax"}});
    </script>
```

This json script can not create the drop down.I throght that product.js not initialize for that.i have add  prototye js ,configurable js and product js with this ajax

Comment: what do you mean by "Quick View"

Comment: yes..you  got right

Comment: I am still not sure what page this is talking about